# Problem with undefined value in class function when passing though express router

Tags: node.js, node8.2

I have a simple class in node 8 but having an issue with `this` value.

```
module.exports = class Controller {
    constructor() {
        this.service = new Service();
    }
    create(request, response, next) {
        try {
            const body = request.body;
            this.service.create(body)
            console.log(this.service)// Undefined
        } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
```

The problem which I'm having is `this` value is undefined. 
A controller above is trigger by the router:

```
const Router = require("express").Router;
const Controller = require("./controller");

module.exports = class NewRouter {
    constructor() {
        this.router = new Router();
        this.controller = new Controller();
        this.initRoutes();
    }
    initRoutes() {
        this.router.post("/setup", this.controller.create);
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code? Looks like you're trying to refer to a NewRouter within the NewRouter class.

Comment: Code updated. This was a mistake in copy-paste from original code

Comment: Are you sure this `console.log(this.service)` results in undefined? The reason I ask is because the line above would error first, `this.service.create(body)`.

Comment: Debug the line in the constructor: `this.service = new Service();` - Is `this.service` undefined at that point?

Answer (score 0):

I think I sorted the problem but really don't like the solution

```
this.router.post("/setup", this.controller.create.bind(this.controller));
```